# Many of the commands are missing in CLI

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, cli, command

I have installed a latest magento version 2.4.6 on my machine. The setup is complete, but I can not able to execute most of Magento's commands.

If I do `php bin/magento` it gives me only below list of commands.

```
Available commands:
  completion
  help
  list
 admin
  admin:user:create
 app
  app:config:import
 events
  events:generate:module
 i18n
  i18n:collect-phrases
  i18n:pack
 info
  info:adminuri
  info:backups:list
  info:currency:list
  info:dependencies:show-framework
  info:dependencies:show-modules
  info:dependencies:show-modules-circular
  info:language:list
  info:timezone:list
 maintenance
  maintenance:allow-ips
  maintenance:disable
  maintenance:enable
  maintenance:status
 module
  module:config:status
  module:disable
  module:enable
  module:status
  module:uninstall
 sampledata
  sampledata:deploy
  sampledata:remove
 setup
  setup:backup
  setup:config:set
  setup:db-data:upgrade
  setup:db-schema:upgrade
  setup:db:status
  setup:di:compile
  setup:install
  setup:performance:generate-fixtures
  setup:rollback
  setup:static-content:deploy
  setup:store-config:set
  setup:uninstall
  setup:upgrade
```

I have tried, setting permissions, clearing var, generated, pub directories, correcting owner of the file, but the issue is still not resolved.
I can execute any command from this list without any issue, but all other commands I run, throws error.

```
 There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup doesn't finish properly. Please check your `config.php` and `env.php` under `app/etc` folder. Finding some working files to compare with your current files.

In the past, I faced missing `install`

```
'install' => [
        'date' => 'Thu, 09 Feb 2023 05:00:32 +0000'
    ]
```

in `env.php`

Answer (score 1):

From your Magento root:

```
rm -Rf var/cache/*
rm -Rf generated/* (or rm -Rf var/generation/* depending on your Magento version)
```

Run this commands

Answer (score 1):

Please check your **env.php** under **app/etc** folder with the help of another working setup. there was something missing that's why to occur this issue

otherwise,

Remove htdocs

```
rm -rf htdocs/*

and re-install the Magento setup
```